# How to auto include to use own class with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using CodeIgniter. I want to use my own class to pass as an argument inside controller functions.

Normally, I can put this class in a folder and include it to `MY_Controller` with its path. But I want to learn if there is a way to do this in CodeIgniter. I can't put it in libraries folder and can't use loader class because it tries to create an instance of an object, but I want to create instance whenever I want. Loader class gives an error if my own class need constructor parameters.

What is the best way to do that? 
Which is the best folder to put in it?

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. Consider this example

```
<?php
Class Home extends CI_Controller{

     public $arg1 = 1;
     public $arg2 = 2;

     function index($this->$arg1 , $this->$arg2){ //or function index()
      //Then inside function 
      //$vara = $this->$arg1 , $varb = $this->$arg2;



     }

}
```